# Increment PHP variable on page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

the title says all. I have a PHP variable and i need to increment that variable every time the page refresh. 
Is that possible to do?

Comment: You need to store it somewhere like in a session or a cookie, variables do not persist data through different requests.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show the code and we can help further...

Comment: @Sirence -- PHP _can_ indeed preserve data, in it's $_SESSION of course :)

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: if(($pages_number<=1) || ($refresh_parameter==0)){
 $row_start=1;
 $row_end=$max_num_prenotations;
        }     I have a my SQL query, but i just wanna take results from a start row to an end row. As you can see from this tiny snippet, the start row and the end row both depend on this $refresh_parameter. I wanted to increment this at every page refresh, so that the start and the end row can change with this variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
server.php

<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
error_reporting(0);

if(!isset($_SESSION['increment'])){
    $_SESSION['increment'] = 0;
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    $_SESSION['increment']++;
}

print($_SESSION['increment']);
exit();

?>
```

Now create your html page or php (it's up to you).

```
index.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Increment Ajax</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="#" id="linkIncrement">Increment</a>
        <div id="result" style="padding: 5px 8px; border: 1px solid #bbb">
        </div>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $.get("server.php", function (data) {
                    $("#result").html(data);
                });
                $("#linkIncrement").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "server.php",
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#result").html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If its for temporary, that is if you want to track before user leaves your website then session would be good option

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION["refreshed_round"])){
    $_SESSION["refreshed_round"]=0;
}
$_SESSION["refreshed_round"]++;
echo "User refreshed: " . $_SESSION["refreshed_round"];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to keep track of variable between requests.

To count all refreshes, from different users, you need to save current count in a file or database as session/cookie applies to each user (each new user will start from 0).